# Adding an inverse of $(2, 0)$ to $\Bbb{R\times R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

This is a problem from Artin:

> Describe the ring obtained by adding an inverse of $(2, 0)$ to $\Bbb{R\times R}$.

I can see that this also adds inverses for all elements of the form $(a, 0)$, but how do I proceed from here?

I'd like a small hint.

Comment: What are the operations considered on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$?

Comment: Elementwise addition and multiplication.

Comment: Have you read about localization yet?

Comment: @VJP Yes, I have. I haven't used it much besides proving that localizations at prime ideals are local rings. It seems that this ring is the localization of $\Bbb{R\times R}$ at the multiplicative set 
$$\{(1,1), (1,0), (2,0), (4,0), \ldots\}$$, but how do I describe that further?

Comment: i.e. as a quotient of some "well-known" ring, etc.

Comment: When you localize to the set, what do the elements of localization look like?

Comment: Quotients of the form $$\frac{(a,b)}{(2, 0)^n}?$$
That probably does not exclude $(1,0)$, since that can be remedied by adding a factor of $2$ to the numerator.

Comment: Yes. Now, what happens when you add an inverse to a zero divisor like $(2,0)$?

Comment: Um, I think then every element is zero. Is this justified? 
$$a = a\times 1 = a\times(r\times (2,0)) = a\times(r\times (0,0)/r) = 0$$[Wikipedia seems to do something similar.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor#Properties)

Comment: @VJP Why don't you add an answer? The hint was very helpful.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon these comments: $(0,0)$ is not the multiplicative identity! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the questions says "*by inverting the element* $(2,0)$".

In terms of rings of fractions this means to look for $R[a^{-1}]$, where $R=\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$, and $a=(2,0)$. (The multiplicative set is $S=\{1,a,a^2,\dots\}$).

> In general, if $R_1,R_2$ are two commutative rings and $S_1,S_2$ are multiplicative sets, $S_i\subset R_i$, $i=1,2$, then $(S_1\times S_2)^{-1}(R_1\times R_2)\simeq S_1^{-1}R_1\times S_2^{-1}R_2$. (The correspondence is easily seen: $\frac{(r_1,r_2)}{(s_1,s_2)}\mapsto(\frac{r_1}{s_1},\frac{r_2}{s_2})$.)

In your case set $S_1=\{1,2,2^2,\dots,\}$, and $S_2=\{0,1\}$. Then $R[a^{-1}]\simeq\mathbb R\times\{0\}\simeq\mathbb R$.

**Edit.** The objection that $S=\{(1,1), (2,0), (2^2,0),\dots\}\subsetneq S_1\times S_2$ is right, but only of pedantic nature. We *obviously* have $S^{-1}(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)=(S_1\times S_2)^{-1}(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Actually, isn't the set $\{(1,1),(2,0),(4,0),\dots\}$?

Comment: Yes since $\{(1,1),(2,0),(4,0),\dots\} \neq S_1 \times S_2$.

Comment: You could add that since every element that is not in $S$ but is in $S_1 \times S_2$ already has an inverse, the localization is the same.

Comment: @user268578, is this why the localization you give is the "correct one"? 

Your method uses a set which has $(1,0)$ and $(2^k,1)$ as extra elements (which are not in the "real" multiplicative set). But the latter are all already invertible, so adding a new inverse makes no difference, and an inverse of $(1,0)$ is already going to be present, since if $r$ is the inverse of $(2,0)$, then $2r \times (1,0) = r \times (2,0) = 1$.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Exactly.

Comment: @user26857 Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the problem from a more general point of view. Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f\in R$. If $f$ is a zero-divisor, you *can't* find an overring $S$ of $R$ such that $f$ is invertible in $S$, because $f$ would remain a zero-divisor also in $S$ and no zero-divisor is invertible, unless we're in the trivial ring.

So the best we can hope to find is another ring $S$ and a ring homomorphism $\lambda\colon R\to S$ such that $\lambda(f)$ is invertible. However we need to keep $\ker\lambda$ as small as possible, because choosing $S$ as the trivial ring would solve the problem, but it would be a very uninteresting solution.

Thus we try to add as little as possible. Suppose we found a solution, that is, a pair $(S,\lambda)$. We shall assume that $S$ is generated by the elements of the form $\lambda(a)$, for $a\in R$, and $\lambda(f)^{-1}$ (such elements are those “reached” by $\lambda$, together with the inverse of $\lambda(f)$). In $S$ we'll have elements of the form $\lambda(f)^{-m}\lambda(a)$, with $m\ge0$ and this is indeed a subring of $S$, because
\begin{align}
\lambda(f)^{-m}\lambda(a)+\lambda(f)^{-n}\lambda(b)
&=\lambda(f)^{-m}\lambda(f)^{-n}\lambda(f^na)+
\lambda(f)^{-m}\lambda(f)^{-n}\lambda(f^mb)\\
&=
\lambda(f)^{-(m+n)}\lambda(f^na+f^mb)\\[6px]
\bigl(\lambda(f)^{-m}\lambda(a)\bigr)\bigl(\lambda(f)^{-n}\lambda(b)\bigr)
&=\lambda(f)^{-(m+n)}\lambda(ab)
\end{align}
In order to save space, we set
$$
\lambda(f)^{-m}\lambda(a)=\frac{a}{f^m}
$$
that's only a *formal* notation. The above relations become
$$
\frac{a}{f^m}+\frac{b}{f^n}=\frac{f^na+f^mb}{f^{m+n}},
\qquad
\frac{a}{f^m}\frac{b}{f^n}=\frac{ab}{f^{m+n}}
\tag{*}
$$
Notice that $\frac{0}{f^m}=0$ (the zero of $S$), because $\lambda(0)=0$ by assumption. Note also that we must have
$$
\frac{a}{f^m}=\frac{f^na}{f^{m+n}}
$$
because $\frac{f}{1}=\lambda(f^{-0})\lambda(f)=\lambda(f)$ *is* invertible in $S$ by assumption.

We now ask when
$$
\frac{a}{1}=\frac{0}{f^n}
$$
should hold. If we multiply both sides by $f^n/1$, we get
$$
\frac{f^na}{1}=\lambda(f^n)\lambda(f^{-n})\lambda(0)=\lambda(0)
$$
Thus
$$
\ker\lambda\supseteq\{a\in R: f^na=0\text{ for some }n\ge0\}
$$
Note that the right-hand side set is an ideal of $R$, which is $\{0\}$ if and only if $f$ is not a zero divisor. (On the contrary, the set coincides with $R$ if and only if $f$ is nilpotent.)

In particular, by the homomorphism theorem, we get an embedding
$$
R/\ker\lambda\to S
$$

Now that we know a bit of what $S$ and $\lambda$ should look like, the trick is to *define* $S$ as the set of equivalence classes of elements of the form $(a,f^m)$ under the equivalence relation
$$
(a,f^m)\sim(b,f^n)
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
f^p(f^na-f^mb)=0
$$
for some $p\ge0$. The equivalence class of $(a,f^m)$ is denoted by $\frac{a}{f^m}$ as before.

The verification that we get a ring by defining operations like in (*) is just tedious. The map $a\mapsto \frac{a}{1}$ is a ring homomorphism and
$$
\ker f=\{a\in R: f^na=0\text{ for some }n\ge0\}
$$
so the kernel *is* as small as possible.

In your specific case, the kernel is
$$
\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:(2^n,0)(a,b)=0\text{ for some }n\ge0\}
=\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}
$$
so the ring we obtain is (isomorphic to) a subring of
$$
\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}/\ker\lambda\cong\mathbb{R}
$$
and it's easy to see $\lambda$ is surjective, in this case.

Comment: In a tedious way you showed that the ring $S^{-1}R$, where $S=\{1,f,\dots,f^n,\dots\}$, is minimal with respect to property that $f$ becomes invertible and for the present question the canonical homomorphism $R\to S^{-1}R$ is surjective and this helps us to find an isomorphism.

Comment: @user26857 I did the assignment “describe the ring…”

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicative set is $S = \{(1,1), (2,0), (4,0), \dots\}$.

Since $(2,0) \cdot (0,a) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, when we add an inverse to $(2,0)$, we make $(0,a)/1 = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let's now show that $S^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}$. Define $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to S^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$ by $f(x) = (x,0)/1$. Since $1 = (1,1)/1 = (1,0)/1 + (0,1)/1 = (1,0)/1$ this is clearly a ring homomorphism. This is also injective, since if $(x,0)/1 = (y,0)/1$, then $2^nx = 2^ny$ for some $n$, but then $x = y$.

All that is left is to show that this mapping is surjective. Let's take $(a,b)/(2,0)^n \in S^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$. We already know that $(a,b)/(2,0)^n = (a,0)/(2,0)^n$. Now, let $x = 2^{-n}a$. Then we get $(2,0)^n \cdot (x,0) = (2^nx,0) = (a,0)$ so $(x,0)/1 = (a,0)/(2,0)^n$. Hence $f$ is surjective, and so $\mathbb{R} \cong S^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I just wanted to give my view of the situation. What I see is that we are simply killing the second component of the product and after that we aren't adding anything new since $\mathbb{R}$ is already a field.